# How to create promise aware numeric input

Tags: ember.js

The following is what I have so far.  The problem is that if `number-input` is bound to an `async` ember-data model property (which will return a promise the frist time an resolve later) - the code below does not work and displays a zero instead.

How can I get it promise aware?

USAGE: (In this case vehicleService is {async : true})

```
{{number-input numberValue=model.vehicleService.cost}}
```

CODE:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var DELETE_KEY = 46;
var INSERT_KEY = 45;
var ZERO_KEY = 48;
var NINE_KEY = 57;

export default Ember.TextField.extend({
  tagName: 'input',
  type: 'number',

  numberValue: function(key, value) {
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
      var number = parseFloat(this.get('value'));
      return isNaN(number) ? 0 : number;
    } else {
      return this.set('value', (value !== void 0 ? '' + value : ''));
    }
  }.property('value'),

  didInsertElement: function() {
    return this.$().keypress(function(key) {
      if ((key.charCode !== DELETE_KEY) && (key.charCode !== INSERT_KEY) && (key.charCode < ZERO_KEY || key.charCode > NINE_KEY)) {
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
App.NumberInputComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['value', 'type'],
  tagName: 'input',
  type: 'number',
});
```

Example --
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jupoworuga/1/edit

Comment: I can still type word characters into that box

Comment: I edited my answer to add 'type' as a attributeBinding.  That'll create a input of type number, but that doesn't stop someone from entering non-numerics into the input.  If thats your goal, you'll have to do something w/ javascript.  (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input for a generic solution).  To use ember add a 'change' action handler, get out the input and remove characters that are not numbers.  If you want I can include a possible solution in my answer.

Comment: Actually now it is not binding properly.  I set it like this `{{number-input value=model.vehiclePriceAdjs.firstObject.amount }}` but the amount is never updated in the ember-data model.

Comment: It seems to have fixed itself when I changed from `Em.Component` to `Em.TextField`, but still the async binding is not working when I load the route the first time.  Instead of the amount it produces 0.

Comment: Can you provide a jsbin (emberjs.jsbin.com)? If the model has the right thing and your component/textfield/whatever does not, then something is wrong with the way you set up your binding.

Comment: In your jsbin (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jupoworuga/1/edit), if you type text in the output field, it does not update the other fields.  It is like a one way binding for some reason.